# how to make .O from .ASM on mac

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

I have the following file hello.asm:

```
section .text
global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
mov edx,len     ;message length
mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80        ;call kernel

mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80        ;call kernel

 section    .data
 msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
 len equ $ - msg              ;length of our dear string
```

On mac, how would i turn it into a .o file. On linux i would do

```
 nasm -f elf64 -o hello.o hello.asm
 ld -o hello hello.o
```

then it could be called with

```
 ./hello
```

I have already installed Xcode and MacPorts, Thanks

Comment: You'll have to install nasm; `port install nasm`. After that the process should be similar, although OS X uses Mach-O binary format instead of ELF, so you'll need to look up what argument to give to `-f`. (Although it might not need that switch at all.)

Comment: @echristopherson i already did      $ sudo port install nasm

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
nasm -o hello.o hello.asm
```

should work, that is, to produce an .o file. typically on OS X  you do something such as:

```
nasm -f macho -o hello.o hello.asm
```

Comment: Not a chance. `nasm -f macho32 hello.asm` (or maybe macho64) I think you may need 0x2000004 for `sys_read` (?) There's a nice manual, but not much info for Mac.Example here: http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=912.0 (not sure it actually works) Not many people doing this - need feedback!

Comment: Actually I think it's just `macho` that would be used, no need for 32 or 64 on the end, so it would be `nasm -f macho -o hello.o hello.asm`.  He didn't say anything about that though, and just wanted an `.o` file - even compiled this won't run on OSX anyway I assume.

Comment: `-f macho` == `-f macho32` (just as `-f elf` == `-f elf32`) I suggest using the "long form" for clarity.

Comment: Here's what I get with that > `nasm -f macho32 -o hello.o hello.asm` ... `nasm: fatal: unrecognised output format `macho32' - use -hf for a list
type `nasm -h' for help`

Comment: valid output formats for -f are (* denotes default):
  `* bin, aout, aoutb, coff, elf, as86 ,obj, win32, rdf, ieee, macho`

Comment: What version? `-f macho32` definitely works for me (but not on a Mac). If `nasm -hf` doesn't list it, don't use it. :) Told ya we needed feedback! That example I linked to will need just `-f macho`...

Comment: `nasm -v` = `NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Aug 13 2013`

Comment: Oh. Yeah, no 64-bit on that version. We're up to 2.11.02. If that's what Apple is distributing, maybe you'd better use it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using OSX version 10.8 also, so they might've included a newer version in 10.9. Apple is always behind the times on what they include within OSX unfortunately (0.98.40 to 2.11.02 is a huge gap).

Comment: I think you've just given me the incentive to compile a new version to use on my system. If you want any feedback in that realm I'll gladly pass it on and let you know how it went — Anyway, thanks for the info Frank :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! fbkotler(pig's tail)myfairpoint(decimal point)net or at the forum.